# ArrayList of objects in a hashmap

Tags: java

I have an arraylist brotherLists which stores values as object.Object's properties are firstname,occupation,genderand id.I also have a map Relatives in which I put this array list,as you can see below.

```
List brothersList=new ArrayList<Object>();

brothersList.add(brother1);
brothersList.add(brother2);
this.getRelatives().put("brother", brothersList);
```

How can I print individual properties(firstname,Occupation etc..) of an object in this arraylist which is now in a map.thanks

Answer (score 2):

Say you wanted to print all names for your brothers array you could do this:

```
for(Entry<String, List> i : brothersList().entrySet()){
        List item = i.getValue();
        for(Object j : item){
            System.out.println(j.firstName); //or use your getter method
        }
 }
```

If you want to get a single item you can do this:

```
List brothersList = brothersList().get("brothers");
Object brother1 = brothersList.get(0); //get by index
String brother1Name = brother1.firstName;
```

If you wanted to get a brother by searching, say, by their name. You would need an additional method which scans through array and finds match i.e.:

```
public String findOccupation(String name){
    List brothersList = brothersList().get("brothers");
    for(Object brother : brothersList){
        if(brother.firstName.equals(name){
           return brother.occupation;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.print(findOccupation("Ajay"));
```

Output:

```
Programmer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the list you just stored in the map, and iterate on it printing the information for each element, you can do:

```
for (Object person : this.getRelatives().get("brother")) {
    System.out.println(person);
}
```

The method `Map.get()` accepts a *key* and retrieves the *value* associated with it that was previously stored in the map.

There seems to be no reason for your list to be a `List<Object>`. Also, you should not declare the variable `brothersList` simply as `List`, without saying which type it contains.

Assuming the name of your custom class is `Person`, you should create a `List<Person>` like this:

```
List<Person> brothers = new ArrayList<>();
```

This way, you will be able to access specific `Person` methods when you iterate on the list contents.

To print the individual properties of the `Person` objects, remember you need to override the method `toString()`:

```
class Person {
    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.firstname + ", " + this.occupation;
    }
}
```